# OnReceive method of my Broadcast Receivers not working in Marshmallow

Tags: broadcastreceiver

I am searching for about 5 hours for a solution to receive my custom broadcast that is sent from a service. All things were good before testing app on android 6.0.
I know that  user-permissions have changed. My manifest.xml file includes:

```html
<application>
<receiver android:name="my_receiver" />
</application>
<permission android:name="name"
          android:label="my_permission"
          android:protectionLevel="signature">
<uses-permission android:name="name"/>
```

But onReceive method is not called?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to mention the action inside the receiver on which you want to call the receiver. in higher sdk version broadcast not work directly you have to register broadcast in main activity.